# PHP Integer base timestamp importing to Java Long base timestamp

Tags: java, php, date

I get Integer timestamp from PHP program, but in Java timestamps are ing Long format. So how can I convert this PHP Integer timestamp to Java Long format and convert that long format to Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP timestamp is number of seconds since 1/1/1970, and Java timestamp is number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. So all you need to do in Java is multiply it by 1000.

```
Date d=new Date((long)phpTimeStamp*1000);
```

Comment: Problem is that when I multiply Integer by 1000, it will overflow, so Is it possible to convert first to long and then multiply wiht 1000?

Comment: Now I got it workign, first convert to long and then multiply with 1000

Comment: but now it multiplies Integer value by 1000 and after that it converts it to long, it should convert it first to long and then multiply. Like this => ((long)phpTimeStamp)*1000

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overflow:

```
Date d=new Date(((long)phpTimeStamp)*1000);
```